# Set the checkbox value to checked by default for super product attribute configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute, checkbox

I would like when we create a new configurable product the checkbox is checked by default

[image: Super product attribute checkbox]

But, I've found in the .phtml

```
<input id="__id___label_use_default" type="checkbox" value="1" " checked="use_default" class="attribute-use-default-label">
```

I would like know where is defined the value use_default?

Thanks, for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I've found my solution in /js/mage/adminhtml/product.js after

```
 var label_readonly = '';
 var use_default_checked = '';
 if (attribute.use_default == '1') {
     use_default_checked = ' checked="checked"';
     label_readonly = ' readonly="readonly"';
 }
```

I've add this :

```
 else if (attribute.use_default == null) {
         use_default_checked = ' checked="checked"';
         label_readonly = ' readonly="readonly"';
 }
```